# Blocking in an async http request with android async http library

Tags: java, android, locking, android-async-http

I know the heading sounds like an oxymoron, however please listen to my case.

I am using refresh token and access token authentication in my android app.
In my app every request goes to a central  Network.Java class through the  `post()` method;

first thing I do in the `post()` method is check if my token is valid. if it is, it proceeds with the request.

if its not, I then call the `refreshAccessToken()` function.

Now in this function I make a http request with the refreshToken to get a new accessToken. However I need this request to only ever be executed one instance at a time.

Use case, user resumes the app. And then 4 requests are all fired off async. They then each see, aah I need to refresh my token, and they all then go and do so.(This causes issues server side and locally). I want the first one to do the token refresh, and the others all to block (On the worker thread) until the first request unlocks it.

here is my refresh function (With my attempt at a lock): 
Sorry it is quite long.

private static synchronized void refreshAccessToken(final Context context, final     TokenResponseHandler callBack) {

```
    //Check if we have a valid refresh token
    if (!refreshToken.isValid(context)) {
        //There is no refresh token, so we have to force the user to login.
        callBack.OnFailed(401, null, null, null);
        //Start the login activity, this also clears all tokens
        startLoginActivity(context);
        //Exit as we can not do anything further
        return;
    }

    //Refresh Token Should be valid here
    //Make request to server for new access token
    final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.add("grant_type", "refresh_token");
    params.add("refresh_token", refreshToken.getToken(context));
    params.add("client_id", "android_app");     

    //Make the request
    httpClient.post(BASE_URL + "Token", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            //Lock this function down so that only one refresh happens at a time
            tokenLock.lock();
            //Check if the access token has not  been refreshed by another thread since we been waiting
            if (accessToken.isValid(context)) {
                //tokenLock.unlock();
                //TODO: end call some how
                callBack.OnSuccess();
               //Check if we need to manually call this.onFinnish(), it might be automatically called when we cancel the request
                this.onFinish();
                this.sendCancelMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            try {
                if (HandleTokenResponse(context, responseBody)) {          
                    callBack.OnSuccess();
                    //Check if we need to manually call this, it might be automatically called when we cancel it
                    this.onFinish();
                    return;
                }                
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to Obtained Access Token By Logging in with a refresh token");
                callBack.OnFailed(500, null, null, new Throwable("Token Parse Error"));
            } catch (Exception ex) {  
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred in token success response", ex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {                
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to Obtained Access Token By Logging in with a refresh token");
            if (responseBody != null) {
                String response = new String(responseBody);
                Log.e(TAG, response);
            }
            //notify parent that error occurred.
            callBack.OnFailed(statusCode, headers, responseBody, error);

            if (statusCode == 400 || statusCode == 401) {
                //NB: We need to check that another thread / request has not already updated the access token.
                if (!accessToken.isValid(context)) {
                    //Bad authentication then we need to login again                        
                    startLoginActivity(context);
                } else {
                    //Continue as normal as the accessToken is ok, was probably updated by another entity                        
                    callBack.OnSuccess();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            tokenLock.unlock();
        }
    });
}
```

Now this is the only way I could get it to block without blocking the UI thread. My `synchronized` deceleration on the function doesn't help as all the function does it fire off an sync task.

However my concern is that The `onStart()` and `onFinnish()` are executed on the UI thread by the library. Which I think is the case? (can anyone confirm)

How can I implement a suitable lock that will not block my UI thread?

Comment: Or you could simply use an AtomicBoolean#compareAndSet as flag to know if a request has to be performed if none is running. Or you can change how those requests are triggered.

Comment: @JEY Ok so you saying `boolean isRefreshignToken`.   And You check it each time. But now what do I do if the boolean is true? I have to wait some how until the boolean is false. I.e. block?

Comment: not a boolean an AtomicBoolean https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html. I miss read your problem. My solution avoid the other call to be performed but you want them to happen.